# Curl returning single output for multiple string inputs

Tags: python, curl, mlflow

I logged a sentiment-analysis model in `Mlflow` with the custom signature, everything is working fine but as soon as I serve the model and hit it with the curl command, then for my multiple inputs it's returning a single output, please help if someone can point to the issue

Curl command i am using :

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:2000/invocations -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"columns": ["text"],"data": [["Its a Bad day"],["what are you"]]}'
```

Output:

```
["negative"]
```

Expected Output:

```
["negative","neutral"]
```

Here is the model signature :

[image]

I have tried two different models, both of them are giving the same issue and if I am trying a model which takes integer values then it's working as expected.

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: This isn't a curl issue, it's just returning whatever the server script output.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an issue with how I have written the curl command, because other than text input everything is giving expected output

Comment: It looks like valid JSON to me.